# mySQL valid bit - alternatives?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Currently, I have a mySQL table with columns that looks something like this:

```
run_date DATE
name VARCHAR(10)
load INTEGER
sys_time TIME
rec_time TIME
valid TINYINT
```

The column `valid` is essentially a valid bit, 1 if this row is the latest value for this (run_date,name) pair, and 0 if not. To make insertions simpler, I wrote a stored procedure that first runs an `UPDATE table_name SET valid = 0 WHERE run_date = X AND name = Y` command, then inserts the new row.

The table reads are in such a way that I *usually* use only the `valid = 1` rows, but I can't discard the invalid rows. Obviously, this schema also has no primary key.

Is there a better way to structure this data or the valid bit, so that I can speed up both inserts and searches? A bunch of indexes on different orders of columns gets large.

Comment: Add a primary key field for a start! That will massively improve performance of searches.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the suggestions below, get rid of `valid` and the `UPDATE` of it.  That is not scalable.

Plan A:  At `SELECT` time, use 'groupwise max' code to locate the latest `run_date`, hence the "valid" entry.

Plan B:  Have two tables and change both when inserting:  `history`, with `PRIMARY KEY(name, run_date)` and a simple `INSERT` statement; `current`, with `PRIMARY KEY(name)` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  The "usual" `SELECTs` need only touch `current`.

Another issue: `TIME` is limited to `838:59:59` and is intended to mean 'time of day', not 'elapsed time'.  For the latter, use `INT UNSIGNED` (or some variant of `INT`).  For formatting, you can use `sec_to_time()`.  For example `sec_to_time(3601)` -> `01:00:05`.